# Accessing Mipmap levels in Metal

Tags: ios, graphics, metal

I'm new to programming in Metal, and I'd like to know how to access specific mipmap levels of a texture. I can use the BlitEncoder to get the mipmapping done, but I'm not quite sure how to access specific miplevels for my use.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check my https://github.com/haawa799/MipMaper for details.

But the short answer is - you use this to get raw bytes from **MTLTexture**:

```
var region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, mipmapedWidth, mipmapedHeight)
var pointer = malloc(UInt(rowBytes * mipmapedHeight))
texture.getBytes(pointer, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, fromRegion: region, mipmapLevel: mipLevel)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I'll check this, and get back asap.

Answer (score 1):

If your app crash  in the line

```
texture.getBytes(pointer, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, fromRegion: region, mipmapLevel: mipLevel)
```

Please pay attention the code

```
   self.metalLayer.framebufferOnly = YES;
```

you should set as the following

```
self.metalLayer.framebufferOnly = NO;
```

Good luck!